# React.js - Prevent Webpack from packing CSS files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack-2, software-packaging

How can I prevent Webpack from packing CSS files more than ones? My team are developing an app in React.js with the following architecture:

Each component has a CSS file, and we need Webpack will packing this CSS JUST with the component it belongs to. Right now, the issue is that Webpack is packing the CSS files in the component directory (which is good for us) AND in ALL their dependencies components. As a result, the css file appears many many times, in different places, and make our app styles impossible to maintain. Any ideas?

Comment: post your Webpack config first.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Code Splitting` option of webpack . **[Doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html)**

Using this configuration your bundle size will be reduced and performance will improve.